# I add C:\MinGW\bin to my path using the command prompt but after a while it goes away

Tags: mingw, command-prompt

So I add `C:\MinGW\bin` to my path using `C:\User\Juan>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin"`and it shows success stating the

> fatal error

after typing in gcc but after I close and open the command prompt again, I type in gcc and it says

> it's unrecognized

. I looked at my environmental variables and it's still there but it won't recognize it. Am I doing something wrong? (I'm new to coding and not very good at setting up the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd` as administrator and use the `/M` flag like:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin"
```

The reason for using `/M` is that it sets the variable at the system scope, and not at the user scope.

Alternatively, look into a tool like [pathed](http://www.p-nand-q.com/download/gtools/pathed.html).